# How can I improve my renegade row?

Tags: dumbbells, back, core, stability

I've been using the ASICS Studio app for workouts recently. I've seen an improvement in my ability to do several exercises, but one of the ones that I still struggle with is the renegade row. I'm not surprised - some research has indicated that this is a more challenging exercise. Are there other exercises that I can do with body weight, dumbells, or kettlebells that are a good substitute for a renegade row? Are there modifications that I can make to build the strength and stabilization necessary to do a full renegade row?

Answer (score 1):

The difficulty of renegade rows comes from your body resisting twisting on itself and falling on the ground when you pull one arm up.

Rotation and contra-rotation of the body is controlled by latissimus dorsi, spinal erectors, external and internal obliques, lower abdomen and by pulling the opposing scapula the trapezius. Teres and rhomboids can help too.

Holding a simple one arm plank with no weight trains the same exact muscles in an isometric fashion.
What adding a rowing motion with weight does is training  the lats, rhomboids, teres, trapezius and shoulders in a dynamic fashion.

If you can't do renegade rows, holding an one arm plank is a beginner friendly exercise to build the needed strength.

Comment: Just to make sure I'm clear, it would be an extended plank on one hand, not on one forearm? That makes the most sense since the renegade row is in a push-up position on your hands.

Answer (score 0):

Ring rows but explosive.

Inverted inclined dips

Front lever pull ups

Those are the only rowing variations that activate the abdomen.

Comment: I'm restricted to body weight, dumbells, and kettlebells. From what I'm looking at, none of these meet those criteria and require some other piece of equipment that I don't have. I'm also not limited to rowing variations - any exercise or set of exercises would work for me.